# Static URL for a JDK?

Tags: installation, licensing, nsis, java

I'm building an NSIS installer to install my application under Windows, and it will check if a user has a JDK (>= 1.5) and download and launch the installer for it if they do not.

While I have seen URLs for use in downloading JREs, I have not seen ones for the JDK.  If I copy and paste the URL I finally get after clicking through several pages to get the Windows (32-bit) (with nothing else bundled) JDK, the URL changes every time.

My users are not technically savvy and may not be able to download the JDK themselves from [the starting page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), so making them do so is suboptimal.

Is there a URL I can consistently use to download the JDK?

Comment: Btw, why do you need a JDK and not simply the JRE?

Comment: @arnaud - my program, Enchanting ( http://enchanting.robotclub.ab.ca ) lets children use graphical blocks to assemble code for their Lego Mindstorms NXT robots, emits the code as Java, and compiles it with leJOS (Java for the NXT), which requires a JDK.

Answer (score 3):

Google reports 0 results on a query:

> "jdk-6u23-windows-i586.exe" site:sun.com

So, I suppose there are no such web directory at the official site.

**Solution** 1: You can use [this stable link](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u23-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer) to the particular JDK version and update it in future versions of your installer.

**Solution** 2: You need a JDK, but it is not fully redistributable. If you need only a compiler from JDK then you may try to **join** a redistributable **JRE** with a redistributable **javac.exe** and bundle it with your application (see [JRE Version 5.0 README](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/jre/README)):

> The J2SE(TM) Runtime Environment (JRE) is intended for software developers 
>   and vendors to redistribute with their applications.
>
> **...**
>
> Redistributable **JDK**(TM) Files
>
> The limited set of files from the JDK listed below may be included in 
>   vendor redistributions of the J2SE Runtime Environment.  All paths 
>   are relative to the top-level directory of the JDK.
>
> **...**
>
> The javac bytecode compiler, consisting of the following files:
>
> bin/**javac.exe** [Microsoft Windows]
>      lib/tools.jar [All platforms]

**Solution** 3: Download all JRE (pure or joined with the compiler) versions a priori to your application's web directory. You should check twice a [license agreement](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/source_license.html) before.

Comment: This is great.  I'd love to go with solution 2 or 3, but in reading the license carefully, I'm not sure I can.  In particular, point c of the acceptable terms states: "your Programs are only intended to run on Java-enabled general purpose desktop computers and servers" and the program that is compiled by javac is intended to run on a robot that does not use general-purpose PC parts.

Comment: Solution 1 works until Oracle changes the download URL. Setting up a simple redirect would make this much easier to maintain. Setup http://myserver.com/downloadjdk to use mod_rewrite to send a 302 redirect to the current location. This way you don't have to push a new binary when the download link changes.

Comment: @Uriah - Brilliant idea!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I think the answer is no, at least not on the sun site directly. You could however bundle the JDK in with the application directly (it'll make for a huge footprint, but if the majority of your users won't have a JDK installed and aren't "technical" enough to install it this is an acceptable route to go down in my opinion.)

Comment: To bundle the JDK you would have to pay Oracle for a special license - they don't allow that, only unmodified distribution of the JRE.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - I thought the JDK was distributable as well as the JRE.

Comment: @Yishai: I think this has changed. According to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html#redistribution it seems that you **are** allowed to redistribute the JDK if it's not modified.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: thanks for that, seems I wasn't going so crazy after all! I was sure I read that the JDK was distributable somewhere.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: **Redistribution** chapter is followed by **Redistributable JDK Files** chapter, so it is not fully redistributable.

Comment: @Developer2: when I go through the list of JDK files that you are allowed to distribute, this is nearly the complete JDK as far as I can tell. From a quick glance I cannot see anything that is missing there (the important parts like tools.jar, apt, javac, jar are included). So essentially one can create a bundle that includes everything important from the JDK.

Comment: @a_horse, I didn't know that, thanks. However when I read it, it is basically allowing you to redistribute *some* of the JDK. If leJOS requires the JDK standard directory structure, or something else of the JDK it may or may not work. It would certainly require testing.

Answer (score -4):

It's a bit off topic, but for easily deploying java applications, you might look at java webstart.

Comment: Java Web Start will not automatically download a JDK, will it?

Comment: Sadly, it only automatically installs the JRE, not the JDK ..and I've no idea whether the latter one would be possible or not.